# problems with android maps apiv2 after signing apk

Tags: android, google-play, google-maps-api-2

I'm having a serious problem

When i build the apk via Eclipse everithing fine and the map is working very well

But when i sign my apk with Eclipse and move the signed apk to my phone the map activity not working, its not collapse it just show gray screen

I don't know what im doing wrong

I made all by using guides and i think everithing is fine

Does it happens to somebody that can help me solve this problem?

I pass the dead line that i should upload my app and i'm really nervous

Please help me.

Thanks for all answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maps api key is based on the keystore sha1 hash and the package name. When you sign your apk, the sha1 hash changes (because you are signing with a different keystore).

Just add the sha1 hash of the new keystore, and the package name to a new line in the  **Key for Android apps (with certificates)** section, under the API Access section in the Google Api Console. It's exlained here as well: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start.

Comment: **Note:** I tried this and it didn't work.  I even deleted the existing key and created a new one with both fingerprints to no avail.  After giving up and going to bed...  it worked fine the next morning!  Apparently, it *sometimes* takes time (an hour or more) for changes to the keys to propagate among Google services.

Comment: Loved one :) Really Thankful.

Comment: Same problem into my app i have try to do but it is not solve. How can i solved this issues?

Answer (score 0):

use your debug keystore to sign the apk or else you have genreate new api key with the sha1 the keystore which you want to export the project.

Comment: try that but google said that your aok was built in debug mode. thanks for the reply